# echo variables in powershell using Write-Output

Tags: windows, powershell

I've just set a couple of variables in Windows 10 using the control panel.

Variable: `TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID`
Variable Value: `my_account_sid`

Variable: `TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN`
Variable Value: `my_twilio_auth_token`

I do `refreshenv` in powershell so I can see the new values.

But when I do:

```
Write-Output "$TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"
Write-Output "$TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"
```

I just get blank lines instead of the values. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Powershell you can use the `ENV:VariableName` drive to call environment variables.

Example:

```
Get-ChildItem ENV:systemroot

Name                           Value
----                           -----
SystemRoot                     C:\WINDOWS
```

In your case you can call it as `Write-Output "ENV:TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"`